# Export an SSRS report to unique PDFs (By grouping)

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, export, grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there a way to build a report in SSRS and have it export/email to unique PDFs. Lets say my report generates 10 sets of data, for 10 customers (grouped by customer number), I want to be able to create 10 distinct PDF documents.

Right, now the user runs the report by customer number and gets output and saves it to PDF. What they are looking to do is batch run it (pull a list of customer numbers) and this we can do in the code. However, then it will generate one 20 page (10 customers - 2 pages a customer) document, and save it to one PDF. How can I break the pages by each group and save it to unique PDFs.

Comment: have you looked into data driven subscription? Depends onthe version of SQL Server you have